# Can you use the Seeking Spell metamagic feat with the spell Fireball?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats, metamagic

The [Seeking Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/seeking-spell-metamagic) metamagic feat says:

> In order to benefit from this feat, the selected spell must have a
>   range greater than touch and target one or more creatures, or it must
>   require the caster to make a ranged touch attack.

When aiming a [Fireball](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball) it says:

> You point your finger and determine the range (distance and height) at
>   which the fireball is to burst. A glowing, pea-sized bead streaks from
>   the pointing digit and, unless it impacts upon a material body or
>   solid barrier prior to attaining the prescribed range, blossoms into
>   the fireball at that point. An early impact results in an early
>   detonation. **If you attempt to send the bead through a narrow passage,
>   such as through an arrow slit, you must “hit” the opening with a
>   ranged touch attack, or else the bead strikes the barrier and
>   detonates prematurely.**

Fireball is normally an Area spell but has a caveat that requires a ranged touch attack roll. Does this allow you to apply Still Spell to a Fireball shot through a ring to make it hit any target in range?

Comment: Did you mean to say Still Spell in your last sentence rather than Seeking Spell as linked above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No, Seeking Spell does not work with fireball.

[Seeking Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/seeking-spell-metamagic) states:

> A seeking spell’s range can bend around obstacles to reach the intended target. You can define the route yourself or unambiguously identify a target and allow the spell to determine its own path. However, the spell fails if it would have to travel farther than its maximum range to reach the identified target. A ranged attack roll made to deliver a seeking spell is not subject to cover or concealment. **In order to benefit from this feat, the selected spell must have a range greater than touch and target one or more creatures, or it must *require* the caster to make a ranged touch attack.**

If we look at [Fireball](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball), we see:

> **Area** 20-ft.-radius spread
>
> [...]
>
> If you attempt to send the bead through a narrow passage, such as through an arrow slit, you must “hit” the opening with a ranged touch attack, or else the bead strikes the barrier and detonates prematurely.

Fireball does not have a target line of one or more creatures, nor does it *require* the caster to make a ranged touch attack. There are just instances where you need to do so.

An example of a spell where you're required to make a ranged touch attack is [Scorching Ray](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scorching-ray/), which states:

> Each ray **requires** a ranged touch attack to hit and deals 4d6 points of fire damage.

---

### A tangent on the usage of Seeking Spell.

If we look at the [rules for magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Line_of_Effect) we see:

> **A line of effect is a *straight, unblocked path* that indicates what a spell can affect.** A line of effect is canceled by a solid barrier. It’s like line of sight for ranged weapons, except that it’s not blocked by fog, darkness, and other factors that limit normal sight.
>
> **You must have a clear line of effect to any target that you cast a spell on or to any space in which you wish to create an effect. You must have a clear line of effect to the point of origin of any spell you cast.**

Seeking spell allows us to bypass the requirement of having a straight unblocked path for casting a spell.

This means that spells like [Magic Missile](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-missile/) or [Scorching Ray](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scorching-ray/), could be cast if you have line of sight to a target, but not line of effect. It also allows you to ignore [Cover and Concealment](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Cover) with spells like [Searing light](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/searing-light/) or [Scorching Ray](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scorching-ray/), helping to increase your odds of hitting a creature.

Comment: In order to benefit from this feat, the selected spell must have a range greater than touch and target one or more creatures, **or** it must require the caster to make a ranged touch attack.

Comment: @Sandwich that is what I stated? What's your point?

Comment: The "or" is a conditional statement. If either side of that statement is true at any point, the statement evaluates to true. Therefore, if there's an instance where you are required to use a touch attack with a fireball, the feat would apply.

Comment: @Sandwich Except the spell does not *require* a ranged touch attack, there's an instance where you **can** use one, but there is no requirement to do so.

Comment: If you want to hit an arrow slit with a fireball, you are required to make a ranged touch attack if you want to proceed with your action. While you have the option to do so, if you want to take that action, it becomes a requirement.

Comment: @Sandwich Incorrect, having the option to choose to do something, makes that not a requirement. Choosing to go left at a fork in the road, does not mean it is required to go left, you just have chosen to do so. Similarly, choosing to make a ranged touch attack with fireball, does not make it a requirement.

Comment: In order to fire a fireball through an arrow slit, you are 100% required to make an attack roll. You don't have the option to not make an attack roll if your intent is to fire a fireball through cover. Having hundreds of options doesn't mean that one will not eventually set the "Must make attack roll" flag to True, which is all that it would take to allow the usage of the feat.

Comment: Even if it was allowed it would not break game balance to do so. It is a fringe case and would affect the game very little.

Comment: "Having hundreds of options doesn't mean that one will not eventually set the "Must make attack roll" flag to True, which is all that it would take to allow the usage of the feat." Incorrect, in order for the usage of an attack roll to be a requirement for the spell, it must be required for all options of the spell. Otherwise it's just that, an option, not a requirement. I never say it would break game balance to do so, it wouldn't be a bad houserule to allow it's usage on fireball, but that's still not how it works in the rules.

Comment: Without an official ruling your guess as to how it works is just as conjectural as mine is.